# How to find the highest value for each day inside a specific time window in a Pandas DataFrame

Tags: pandas, dataframe

I have a dataframe with values for 5 minute intervals over several days. I want to find the highest value between 09:30-09:55 for each day. This code gives me the highest value in this time window for all days, but I need it for every single day:

```
import pandas as pd
import yfinance as yf

# Get the data
data = yf.download(tickers="MSFT", period="5d", interval="5m")

df = pd.DataFrame(data)
df = df.between_time('9:30', '09:55')
x = df.High.idxmax(axis=0)

print(x, df.High[x])
```

What I tried: Create an array of unique trading days and then loop over this list. This seems to work, but also seems to be very complicated and prone to errors. Is there an easier solution, maybe even without looping?

```
# Build a list of trading days (MON-FRI)

start_date = date(2024, 3, 11)
end_date = date(2024, 3, 16)
ONE_DAY = timedelta(days=1)
monToFri = set([0,1,2,3,4])

def gen_trading_days(start, end):
    thisDay = start

    while thisDay < end:
        dow = thisDay.weekday()
        while dow not in monToFri:
            thisDay += ONE_DAY
            dow = thisDay.weekday()
        yield thisDay
        thisDay += ONE_DAY

trading_days = []        
for i in gen_trading_days(start_date, end_date):
    trading_days.append(str(i))

# Loop through list of trading days and filter for day and time window
for i in range(len(trading_days)):
    startDate = trading_days[i]
    #print(startDate)
    dt_startDate = datetime.strptime(startDate, '%Y-%m-%d').date()
    dt_range = pd.date_range(start=startDate+" 09:30:00-04:00", end=startDate+" 09:55:00-04:00", freq='5min')
    dr = df[df.index.isin(dt_range)]
    x = dr.High.idxmax(axis=0)
    print(x, df.High[x])
```

This is my output for above code:

```
2024-03-14 09:40:00-04:00 424.95001220703125
--------------
2024-03-11 09:30:00-04:00 404.20001220703125
2024-03-12 09:30:00-04:00 409.677001953125
2024-03-13 09:30:00-04:00 418.17999267578125
2024-03-14 09:40:00-04:00 424.95001220703125
2024-03-15 09:30:00-04:00 422.6000061035156
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can also, use [`pd.DateTimeIndex.normalize`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DatetimeIndex.normalize.html#pandas-datetimeindex-normalize):

```
df['High'].groupby(df.index.normalize()).max()
```

Output:

```
Datetime
2024-03-11 00:00:00-04:00    404.200012
2024-03-12 00:00:00-04:00    409.677002
2024-03-13 00:00:00-04:00    417.309998
2024-03-14 00:00:00-04:00    424.950012
2024-03-15 00:00:00-04:00    422.600006
Name: High, dtype: float64
```

Answer (score 0):

Use `pd.Grouper`:

```py
idx = df.groupby(pd.Grouper(freq="D"))["High"].idxmax().to_list()
df.loc[idx]
```

Comment: For OPs desired result a simple `max` would suffice: `df.groupby(pd.Grouper(freq='D'))['High'].max()`

Comment: Thank you! This seems to work fine as long as there are no days without data (weekends, bank holidays). I also tried freq="B" but still get an error message "attempt to get argmax of an empty sequence" if I pull data for more than the last 5 days. I tried to filter the dataframe for na values, but that doesn't solve the problem because the error occurs inside tis line:
```idx = df.groupby(pd.Grouper(freq="B"))["High"].idxmax().to_list()```
Any suggestions?